# php DirectoryIterator listing xlsx files with ~ file name as there is a opened excel sheet in the folder, how to ignore these

Tags: php, file, directory, iterator

```html
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(K_file_location);
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        $file_name=$fileinfo->getFilename();
        $spl = new SplFileInfo($file_name);
        if (strcmp($spl->getExtension(), "xlsx") == 0)
            if (strpos($file_name, '~') != true)
                $upload_file_list[] = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    }
}
```

i tried adding strpos but seems to be not working. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

```
// PHP 8.0
if (!str_ends_with($spl->getExtension(), "xlsx")) {
    if (!str_begins_with($file_name, '~'))
```

stripos returns the position of a substring, or false if it isn't found

**===** is exactly equal, meaning both the type (boolean, integer, etc) and value are the same

Since **~** is at the beginning of the name, the position is 0, which is **==** to false, but not **===** exactly equal.

```
// < PHP 8.0
if (stripos($spl->getExtension(), "xlsx") === false)
    if (stripos($file_name, '~') !== 0)
```

Comment: the file extension already works, i am still getting a file  
~$filename.xlsx is added to the upload file list, which i actually want to ignore

Comment: instead of strpos($file_name, '~') != true

this actually works. 

(stripos($file_name, "~") === false)